# Which statistical test is better? (chi square)

Tags: chi-squared-test

I am wondering about the chi square test and what will give me more reliable/better results.

I have four categories
Aa
Ab
Ba
Bb

I want to test if these four categories are in a 1:1:1:1 ratio, however; I also can add up the Ba+Bb and Aa + Ab categories and test if these follow a 1:1 ratio. Which test is more accurate?

Comment: Please clarify the nature of your data.  Are you perhaps trying to describe a $2\times 2$ contingency table?  What values do you have for these categories -- counts, proportions, averages, sums, something else?  How were these values observed?  What are typical values you have for these categories?  *All these things matter.*

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see if they occur in a 1:1:1:1 ratio, you would have to test the 4 frequencies simultaneously.

For example if

- Aa = 50
- Ab = 0
- Ba = 25
- Bb = 25

then clearly the four categories are not occurring at a 1:1:1:1 ratio.  But the second test would show that Aa+Ab and Ba+Bb occur at a 1:1 ratio.

The choice in tests depends on which type of difference you want to detect.

Comment: "Test them all separately" would be invalid because the four tests are interdependent.

Comment: @whuber you are right, I'll try to clean up the wording